# nil value being assigned in || test

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to do a conditional assignment:

```
entries = (@instance_1 || @instance_2)
```

If `@instance_1` is nil, I'd like `@instance_2` to be assigned to `entries`. In this case, I know that one or the other will have a value.

However, I'm running into an issue where `@instance_1` is nil, and `@instance_2` has a value, but `@instance_1` is being used in the assignment.

Am I approaching this incorrectly?

This is in the context of a Rails app. I dumped out some data from Pry so you can see how it's reacting:

Here's where the Pry statement is taking place:

```
entries = (@time_entry || @times_entries)
binding.pry
```

Now, the value of `entries`:

```
[1] pry(#<TimelogController>)> entries
=> nil
```

The value of `@time_entry`:

```
[2] pry(#<TimelogController>)> @time_entry
=> nil
```

And the value of `@time_entries`:

```
[3] pry(#<TimelogController>)> @time_entries
=> [#<TimeEntry:0x00000006f6f878
  id: 1838,
  project_id: 10,
  user_id: 8,
  issue_id: 1481,
  hours: 1.0,
  comments: "hey now",
  activity_id: 9,
  spent_on: Fri, 20 Nov 2015,
  tyear: 2015,
  tmonth: 11,
  tweek: 47,
  created_on: Fri, 20 Nov 2015 20:07:06 UTC +00:00,
  updated_on: Fri, 20 Nov 2015 20:07:06 UTC +00:00,
  freshbooks_time_entry: nil>]
```

So in this situation, it is returning nil, even though the second argument `(@time_entries)` has a value.

Comment: There's a typo in your code: `@instance 2` instead of `@instance_2`. This would cause a SyntaxError, however, so I suspect you haven't posted your actual code.

Comment: You sure about your assumptions?

Comment: @Jordan yeah, not my actual code.  Just an example.  Edited.  @Dave Newton I assume you mean my assumptions about their values:  I used `pry` and found that @instance_1 was nil, and @instance_2 was a populated Object, yet entries was set equal to nil

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please provide a complete example, where you assign instance_1, instance_2, and then entries

Comment: Your approach is correct. Period. The only subtlety there is that `false` will be treated the same way as `nil` which is a problem sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for everyones input.  I've updated my question with output from Pry to show whats happening

Comment: Something else besides what we can see is happening then. Is `entries` an AR relation? There's context here that must explain the observed behavior.

Comment: Im not sure why this is getting a close request.  I believe I followed all the rules as far as what the problem was, what I expected, and what I tried.  And as it turned out, I had provided all the necessary information to solve the issue

Comment: @dtj Because typos are a close reason. I mean, simply typing in the logical expression you were trying instead of relying on the code would probably have led to the right answer too. Plus everyone saying the construct itself was correct.

Comment: @DaveNewton I understand. But when asked for more info, I didn't hesitate to post it.  And the first line of my edit was in fact the logical expression I was trying.  Also I had titled my edit in block letters so that it was apparent what was new, but it seems somebody edited that out

Comment: No, I mean if you had explicitly typed in the vars, then the expression, it's unlikely the typo would have been repeated. Then when you looked at these code all "wat" the issue would likely be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One says @time_entries and the other says @times_entries

```
entries = (@time_entry || @times_entries)
```

vs.

```
[3] pry(#<TimelogController>)> @time_entries
```

If you change it to

```
entries = (@time_entry || @time_entries)
```

it should work

Comment: ha ding ding ding! I guess the answer wasn't as hidden as we all thought

Comment: @dtj I'd argue the exact opposite; it was hidden enough that people glancing at the code all pretty much said the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Transcript of irb session:

```
irb(main):001:0> @i1 = nil
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> @i2 = 3
=> 3
irb(main):003:0> a = (@i1 || @i2)
=> 3
irb(main):004:0> a = @i1 || @i2
=> 3
```

The problem you describe cannot be reproduced

Edit:
I see your edit. So let me help you to provide a complete example:

```
class TimeEntry
end
@time_entry = nil
@time_entries = [TimeEntry.new]
entries = (@time_entry || @times_entries)
p entries
p @time_entry
p @time_entries
```

And yes, this prints nil as the value for entries. Now I can reproduce, but do not yet have an explanation. Instead I am confused by this. The ruby version I used to execute this example was 1.9.3p484 on ubuntu 14.04

Same strange result with ruby 2.0.0p384. The example skript prints

```
nil
nil
[#<TimeEntry:0x000000020fcd58>]
```

Whereas I would expect the first line to be the same as the third.

Edit: Dane Anderson spotted the typo. Someone might have spotted it earlier if you had provided a complete example from the start.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I've updated my question with output from pry so you can see exactly what each parameter is outputting

Comment: It doesn't for me, it prints the array containing the single `TimeEntry`.

Comment: @Ludwig Schulze thanks.  Yep, I added the complete example within minutes of posting the question

Comment: Apparently because I didn't duplicate the typo.

Comment: @dtj Ok, I must have missed your complete example, then. But why did you remove it after adding it?

Answer (score 0):

This works for any number of elements:

```
def first_non_nil(*args)
  args.find { |x| !x.nil? }
end

@instance_1 = "hello"
@instance_2 = "world"
entry = first_non_nil(@instance_1, @instance_2)         #=> "hello"
entry = first_non_nil(nil, "world")                     #=> "world" 
entry = first_non_nil(nil, false, "world")              #=> false
entry = first_non_nil("hello", nil)                     #=> "hello" 
entry = first_non_nil(nil, nil)                         #=> nil 
entry = first_non_nil(nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, "hello") #=> "hello"
```

Comment: thanks for your response.  I've updated my question with output from pry so you can see exactly what each parameter is outputting

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing can't be:

```
(true || nil)  # => true
(nil  || true) # => true

(true  || false) # => true
(false || true)  # => true
```

That's right out of Pry.

Replicating what you gave us:

```
require 'date'

class TimeEntry
  def initialize
    @id                    = 1838
    @project_id            = 10
    @user_id               = 8
    @issue_id              = 1481
    @hours                 = 1.0
    @comments              = "hey now"
    @activity_id           = 9
    @spent_on              = Date.parse('Fri, 20 Nov 2015')
    @tyear                 = 2015
    @tmonth                = 11
    @tweek                 = 47
    @created_on            = DateTime.parse('Fri, 20 Nov 2015 20:07:06 UTC +00:00')
    @updated_on            = DateTime.parse('Fri, 20 Nov 2015 20:07:06 UTC +00:00')
    @freshbooks_time_entry = nil
  end
end

@time_entry = nil
@time_entries = [TimeEntry.new]
entries = (@time_entry || @time_entries) # => [#<TimeEntry:0x007f853991dfc8 @id=1838, @project_id=10, @user_id=8, @issue_id=1481, @hours=1.0, @comments="hey now", @activity_id=9, @spent_on=#<Date: 2015-11-20 ((2457347j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, @tyear=2015, @tmonth=11, @tweek=47, @created_on=#<DateTime: 2015-11-20T20:07:06+00:00 ((2457347j,72426s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, @updated_on=#<DateTime: 2015-11-20T20:07:06+00:00 ((2457347j,72426s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, @freshbooks_time_entry=nil>] # !> assigned but unused variable - entries
```

Comment: yes, i know.  However as I've outlined above, it is not responding as expected with the data I'm using.

Comment: You haven't given us enough data, i.e., input and usable code to reproduce the problem. The above examples break it down to the bare logic, which is  how it works. And, that means that what you think should be nil in your code isn't, when the interpreter encounters that expression.

Comment: I outputted the value of each element above as they occur.  Do I need to provide more information than that?

Comment: You need to provide more thorough proof of the problem. Ruby behaves as expected when given the inputs you say. The vast majority of the time this sort of statement/question resolves to being a bug in your code, but with the little you've given us we can't help you.

Comment: fair enough, i'll try put together a stack trace to see whats happening along the way

Comment: A stack trace won't help us. It doesn't show us the code and assignments, besides, it's not the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem, which is a requirement for debugging help. Using a debugger and single step your assignment to `@time_entry` and prior to the assignment to `entries`. That should locate the problem.